# Find a same ID in multiple rows having a date, where a date is null in those rows and a not in other rows for the same ID in SAS?

Tags: sas, duplicates

My dataset looks like this:

[image]

I want to flag/find the rows with the same ID having the event datevent null and the ones where the even date is not null.

I tried the following:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select *, 
case 
when ID in (select distinct ID from HAVE group by ID having count(ID)>1) then 1 
else 0 
end
as IDFlag
from HAVE;
quit;
```

This just gives me all the rows having more than 1 ID, but does not give me information on which rows have the same ID and event date as null and event date as non-null.

Comment: The screenshot you posted - does it show all of the columns in your table? Also, what is the DBMS you're using?

Comment: Yes, that is right. I am using SAS.

Comment: Do you want to flag the observations with missing values?  or do you want a single value per ID that is constant for every observation for that ID?  If so then exactly what is it that you want to test?  do you want to test if it has one and only one non-missing value?  Do you want to test if it has one non-missing value and one or more missing values?  What if it has two non-missing values that are different?  Showing the expected result for the given input would help clarify the ask.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the aggregate functions and GROUP BY cluase.

So if the test is if there are any missing values use

```
select *, max(missing(event_flag)) as IDFLAG
from have
group by ID
```

If the test is that there is both some missing and some non-missing values then try:

```
max(missing(event_flag)) ne min(missing(event_flag)) as IDFLAG
```

Or perhaps you want to make two flags so you can test for the multiple possible combinations.

```
,max(missing(event_flag)) as any_missing
,max(not missing(event_flag)) as any_nonmissing
```